Mypy issue 'name <func> already defined' when using hybrid property and expression of sqlalchemy
Is the a way to solve the issue with mypy and sqlalchemy when defining the expresison of a hybrid property, it triggered name <func> already defined
class User(Base):
    first_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    @full_name.expression
    def name(cls) -> str:
        return cls.first_name + " " + cls.last_name

I don't want to install external stubs package or ignore it with # type : ignore.
Is there a way to rename the expression or something else ?
